# different behaviors of java.lang.Object.wait()

Tags: java, wait, notify

I was trying to use `java.lang.Object.wait()` method and have written 3 different sample codes wherein I am getting different behavior of `wait()` method.

sample 1)

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        synchronized (b) {
            System.out.println("main thread trying to call wait() method"); //--> 3
            b.wait();
            System.out.println("main thread got notification"); 
            System.out.println(b.total); 
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total = 0;
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("child thread starts calculation");  //--> 1
            for (int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
                total = total + i;
            }
            System.out.println("child thread trying to give notification"); //--> 2 
            this.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

sample 2)

```
public class Main{
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new Thread();    
    t.start();
    System.out.println("X"); //--> 1
    synchronized(t) { 
    System.out.println("starting to wait"); //--> 2
    t.wait(10000);
    System.out.println("waiting on t"); //--> 3
    }
    System.out.println("Y"); //--> 4
   }
}
```

sample 3)

```
public class Main{
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     Thread t = new Thread() {public void run() 
                     {System.out.println("I am the second thread.");}};
     t.start();
     System.out.println("X"); //--> 1
     synchronized(t) { 
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         System.out.println("starting to wait"); //--> 2
         t.wait(10000);
         System.out.println("waiting on t"); //--> 3
     }
     System.out.println("Y"); //--> 4
  }
}
```

In sample 1)

**main** thread goes in waiting state **forever** as it has called `b.wait()` method and there is no thread to provide `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on object `b`. There was **child** thread that has already been terminated before **main** thread called `b.wait()` method. 
This output is what I expected.

In sample 2)

**main** thread goes in waiting state for 10 seconds (`t.wait(10000);`) after printing
*X*
*starting to wait*
after 10 seconds **main** thread executes
*waiting on t*
*Y*
This is also my expected output.

In sample 3)

**main** thread is **NOT** going in waiting state (`t.wait(10000);`) even though it is sure that **child** thread would have been **terminated** by the time **main** thread called `t.wait(10000);` 
**So why it didn't wait ?** and straightaway executed
 
*starting to wait

waiting on t

Y*
This is **NOT** my expected output.

Comment: You shouldn't synchronize on an instance of thread, nor use it as monitor. It is confusing, and it doesn't do what you think it does, and iirc it may conflict with the internals of thread.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster - I am aware about what synchronized keyword does. It is a sample code to learn the working of wait() method.

Comment: Like Mark said, don’t synchronize on a Thread object.  Synchronizing on any other object (I recommend `new Object()`) and calling `wait()` on that object will make your `wait` call behave as expected.

Comment: @NathanHughes please see my comments in your answer section. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the first two examples your expectations seem correct. In the third example it seems reasonable to expect that t will finish before the main thread starts waiting, and then the main thread will hang until it times out.

But as you observed, that isn't what happens.

A waiting thread doesn't stop waiting unless interrupted or notified (except for spurious wake ups, but those are the result of unpredictable race conditions; the behavior in the posted code happens reliably, so I think spurious wakeups can be excluded here).

Since there is nothing interrupting the main thread, and its wait is cut short and we've ruled out spurious wakeups, it *must* be receiving a notification. There is only one thing that can provide the notification, and that is the t thread.

For t to notify the main thread it must have been alive at the time that t started waiting. So what is keeping it around?

There is some not-well-known behavior that occurs when a thread terminates. The [API documentation for Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) says:

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

What happens is:

1) t prints its output and is on the way out of its run method.

2) There is a race between t and the main thread to acquire the lock on t. t needs it to call notifyAll, main needs it to enter the synchronized block. The main thread happens to grab the lock first.

3) t hangs around until it can acquire the lock.

4) The main thread enters the wait method (releasing the lock).

5) The t gets the lock and calls t.notifyAll.

5) The main thread is notified and leaves the wait method (reacquiring the lock).

Some lessons:

- Don't synchronize on threads (this is a good example of why the API docs say not to do this, here you inadvertently delayed a thread from dying in a timely fashion).
- If a thread isn't waiting, it doesn't get notified. If a thread starts waiting after the notification has already happened, that notification is lost.
- Don't rely solely on notifications (it makes your code vulnerable to race conditions), instead use notifications along with some condition that the other thread can set. Call wait in a loop with a test condition. If you see the Thread.join source code, it is a good example, it looks something like:

  ```
      while (isAlive()) {
          wait(0);
      }
  ```
- Don't sleep while holding a lock. It makes the system less responsive for no benefit.
- Be very careful about making assumptions about the order things happen in.

Comment: @Nathan - you are saying contradictory things...
"What happens is t prints its output, then the main thread grabs the lock, and t doesn't get a chance to take it back until the main thread waits (releasing the lock).
For t to die, it needs to call notifyAll, and it can't do that without acquiring its own lock. It blocks until it can acquire the lock."

as per your lines above.. thread t is acquiring its lock and calling notifyAll() and then terminating after lock is released by main method. But in real that is the problem, main thread is not even waiting (t.wait(10000);)

Comment: @raven03: the main thread calls wait. The wait is cut short when the notifyAll takes effect, that causes the thread to return from waiting. Of course it needs to re-acquire the lock to do that, but t released it after calling notifyAll so the lock is available. not clear on what is contradictory.

Comment: @NathanHughes how would you explain the output of below program --
public class Main{
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     Thread t = new Thread() {public void run() 
                     {System.out.println("I am the second thread.");}};
     t.start();
     System.out.println("X"); 
     Thread.sleep(4000);
     synchronized(t) { 
         System.out.println("starting to wait"); 
         t.wait(10000);
         System.out.println("waiting on t"); 
     }
     System.out.println("Y"); 
  }
}
here why main thread is not getting notifyAll()

Comment: @raven03: In this code the main thread sleeps before taking the lock. while the main thread sleeps t calls notifyAll and finishes. Then the main acquires the lock and waits until the timeout expires.

Comment: @raven03: is the problem that you’re thinking t.wait makes the t thread wait? That’s not correct, it’s the main thread waiting even though the method is called on t. (this is one of the things about using the lock on threads that causes confusion.)

Comment: apologies for delay in responding. `This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.`
**this.notifyAll** will always call notifyAll method on the thread instance that is about to complete it's execution and terminate?
Also is it applicable for the case when thread terminates due to some unhandled run time exceptions during program execution?

Comment: looking forward to your response.

Comment: @raven03: the documentation doesn't say there are exceptions for those cases so i expect think it would always call notifyAll. if you are curious then you could try it out.

Comment: here `this.notifyAll` means calling notifyAll method on thread instance about to terminate? is it the case **always** thread about to terminate will call notifyAll on its **own** instance? **In other words _this_ keyword does it always refer to the thread about to terminate?**